# how to convert a string in to a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I've wrote a method to encrypt/decrypt a string. Encryption is happening successfully but I cannot manage to make the decryption work... This is the code I have written:

```
public String encrypt(String a, int x) {
     String ret = "";
     String text = a;
     String key = "Bar12345Bar12345"; // 128 bit key

     try {
         // Create key and cipher
         Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

         if(x == 0) { //x==0 means I want to encrypt
             // encrypt the text
             cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
             byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
             ret =new String(encrypted);
         }

         else { //if not 0 I want to decrypt
             // decrypt the text
             byte[] encrypted = text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
             cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
             String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
             ret=decrypted;
         }

    } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I think the problem arise when I'm trying to convert the string into byte array. The error I get is:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

So what is the problem ? If I am not converting the string into byte array in right way, how should I do it ?

Comment: You should use a boolean, not an int.

Comment: You cannot interpret arbitrary ciphertext as UTF (or any other encoding).  You should use Base64.

Comment: hihi yeah yeah but i dont think that is the problem...

Comment: still i am getting an exception "java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: Base64"

Comment: @SLaks is right, you could do `new String(encrypted, "ISO-8859-1")` and `text.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")` and very often that will work. However then you back and forth do a superfluous conversion, use double memory (char is two bytes) and the conversion is not entirely bijective.

Comment: Don't **ever** catch an exception like that, where you don't *handle* the exception and instead return an empty string.